# merge local .net library documentation

Tags: c#, code-documentation

when I press F1 on some .net keyword it takes me to the help for that keyword.
I have a .net library with its documentation. I am using this library.How can I get to the library help with F1 when I press F1 on some function from this library?

in general how can we merge the local documentation with the .net documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need that? The normal way is to provide contextual help for your libraries with intellisense, generating the xml files.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200802/how-do-you-get-the-xml-documentation-to-show-for-a-referenced-c-sharp-library) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238871/how-do-i-add-context-help-to-an-assembly) related entries.

Also:

[What's the XML file that comes together with a .NET assembly file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564336/whats-the-xml-file-that-comes-together-with-a-net-assembly-file)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx

Comment: The IntelliSense feature in Visual Studio only presents a small subset of the documentation which the XML file may include - basically limited to the `<summary>` and `<param>` tags. The <kbd>F1</kbd> integration is used for displaying the extended information for any type/member in the .NET Framework, so for consistency it is nice to support your own SDK documentation in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

Unless that library provides Help 2/3 files, you won't be able to achieve that,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_2

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_Viewer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/), which can generate a Help 1 (.chm) file, an MS Help 2 (.HxS) file, MS Help Viewer (.mshc), and/or a website.

The HTML Help 2.x output includes a valid set of collection files and an H2Reg.exe configuration file to simplify deployment and integration of the help file into existing collections such as those used by Visual Studio.